# Prevent UI-Router state execution on authorization failure but still activate it

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

In my main module's `run` method I have code like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
    if (toState.data && toState.data.access && !Authentication.authorize(toState.data.access, toState, toParams)) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'components/security/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl as ctrl',
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            size: 'sm',
            resolve: {
                reason: function() {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Basically, when you navigate to a state and you're not authenticated a modal window pops up (the same happens when a 401 was received from the API).

In the login modal is a link to the sign up form. Everything works fine except these steps:

- Open the website www.example.com/.
- The "home" state (/) is protected, so the authorize check fails thus this code is executed: `event.preventDefault()` and the modal pops up.
- The user clicks on the "sign up" link: the login modal closes and he goes to www.example.com/signup. This all still works fine.
- Now when you press the back button in the browser the authorize check kicks in again and prevents the state change, thus the url stays at www.example.com/signup.
- When the user logs in the login modal closes and the state loads but here's the problem: he's still at the sign up state instead of / (the home page).

So the problem is of course that `event.preventDefault()` doesn't change the state at all which is handy because no code that depends on the user being logged in runs. But what I really need is that it goes to the state but doesn't actually execute it, if that makes sense. Then pressing the back button would simply go back to the home page and the login modal pops up again. Then when you login you're on the correct state (the home page).

Comment: Had a similar problem - a bit different implementation so hard to see without a plunk - but the solution was `.sync()` - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#urlrouter-1

Comment: I don't really see how `.sync()` can help here? I can't call `event.preventDefault()` AND `.sync()` when you're not authenticated. I'll try to get a plunk up with my implementation, although I suspect that it'll be a lot of work to pull out all the necessary bits and pieces.

Comment: I've sort of solved it by saving my destination state and params in the authentication check, and then calling $state.go after I log in, see http://plnkr.co/edit/k993sRNjBtpzqlENy1f3?p=preview. It's still weird because the url stays at /signup after you press the back button, but at least you're on the correct page after logging in. A better solution would be very welcome!